# How can I add lighting in my bedrooms without too many visible wires?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I will be moving in to my new house in 2 months. My wife and I thought that we might not need ceiling lights, and that our builder charged too much for the lights anyway. We did not order any ceiling lights in the bedrooms, but now we regret the decision.

What are our options for adding lighting to the bedrooms, now that the house is basically complete?

Comment: Your question doesn't clarify the obvious: is it simply lights that are missing from the ceiling, or are there no *receptacles* there for lights? You know, there is a difference between "light" and "electrical/structural box that supports the installation of a light".

Answer (score 1):

What is above the bedroom? The attic, or another floor?
If attic, you may consider running wires to the center of the room's ceiling. You'll need to do some wiring, but it isn't too bad after watching some tutorial videos on YouTube.

If another floor is above, you might be able to do the same thing if a crawlspace is available.

Finally, if you have a light switch on an opposite wall, you may be able to run wire through the wall and add another switch. You can then drill a hole a some distance above the switch for a wall-mounted light, fish wire down, and connect.

Picture wires fished down to a switch a few feet below the light in this picture:

[image: Wall light]

None of these require removal of drywall, which I assume is important to save money.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix lights in to walls or ceiling without any visible wires by running them in the walls. Sure, it would have been easier to have them in place before the plasterboard/drywall was fitted, but you can use fish tape to route wires above the ceiling or behind the walls.

You will need to accept that holes will need to be made, and touching up will be required around fittings and fixtures butv these are easy.